# .dataTable no funciona con tabla dinámica

Tags: php, html5, ajax, datatables

Tengo una duda respecto a la utilización de Datatable. Para poder realizar el filtro en  una tabla dinámica.

**En contexto**
Tengo un archivo  `mercadeo.php` que tiene un `select-option`  y se comunica por `ajax` para realizar una búsqueda de mas datos ( filtros dependientes de otro `select`).

una vez finalizado esta búsqueda en pantalla de 3 datos (Que funciona) el ultimo `ajax`  va  a la pagina `productos.php` realiza una búsqueda y me devuelve 2 tablas la primera he importante es dinamica.  la otra es estática y es como un formulario  x.

Sin embargo quiero agregarle el dinatable.

pero si hago que el ajax. traiga  toda la pagina  con el script de búsqueda de dinatable asi:

```
            <!-- PAGINACION TABLA -->
           <script type="text/javascript"> 
// < ![CDATA[
               $('#TableId').dataTable(
                      {
                    "oLanguage": 
                    {
              "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
              "sLengthMenu":     "No. Registros _MENU_ ",
              "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
              "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
              "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
              "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
              "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
              "sInfoPostFix":    "",
              "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
              "sUrl":            "",
              "sInfoThousands":  ",",
              "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
              "oPaginate": {
                  "sFirst":    "Primero",
                  "sLast":     "Último",
                  "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                  "sPrevious": "Anterior"
              },
              "oAria": {
                  "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                  "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
              }

                    } ,

                  }
                );
 // ]]>     
               </script>
```

Me genera un error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo agrego en la pagina `mercade.php` que es donde llega la tabla después de la búsqueda ( el retorno de  `success : function(datos)` ) No me genera ningún error.

**Pero  no aparecen los filtros.**

He probado esto en otras tablas dinámicas donde no requiero utilizar `ajax`  y funciona perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de que  no estoy teniendo en cuenta ?

Comment: Revisa la pestaña "Network". Tal vez el script del datatable no hay terminado de cargar en la página. Prueba usando `setTimeout` de 1 o 2 segundos para llamar a la función que carga tu dataTable...

Comment: Intenta agregar esto a tu js:  "destroy": true,

Answer (score 3):

Cuando he generado una tabla dinamicamente, aplico el

```
$('#TableId').dataTable();
```

dentro del

```
success : function(datos){}
```

Mira así lo haría.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("GetData", "DRTSolicitudes")",                
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response)
    {               
        //Dibujar tabla
        var html = '';
        var listaJson = $.parseJSON(response);

        $('#tableX tr').remove();

        html += '<thead><tr>';
        html += '<th>' + 'Solicitud' + '</th>';
        html += '<th>' + 'Tarea' + '</th>';
        html += '<th>' + 'Descripción' + '</th>';
        html += '</tr></thead>';

        html += '<tbody>';

        $.each(listaJson, function (k, v) {              

            html += '<tr >';
            html += '<td>' + v.fiSolicitudId + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + v.fcNombreTarea + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + v.fcMotivoSolicitud + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';

        });
        html += '</tbody>';

        $('#tableX').append(html);

        //Datatable

    $('#tableX').dataTable(); 

    },

    failure: function (response)
    {
    console.warn(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response)
    {
    console.warn(response.responseText);     
    }
    });
```

> Por que si lo hago en el document ready me marca el mismo error que a
>   ti.

```
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            $('#tableX').dataTable();
        });
```

Espero te sea útil.